# Cannot remove aspell-en in attempt to fix failed dist-upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

Once, I tried to do a dist-upgrade of a remote Ubuntu 12.04 (I think, or 14.04) system, and the upgrade failed.

Now, that I have physical access to the machine, I am trying to fix it. First I managed to get the `eth0` network interface up by adding eth0 lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` and then rebooting (into Recovery console/terminal); and then I try this:

```
# apt -f install
...
22 upgraded, 464 newly installed, 183 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/257MB of archives.
After this operation, 777 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed.
(Reading database ... 176434 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing aspell-en (7.1-0-1) ...
Can't locate Text/Iconv.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::Iconv module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/DictionariesCommon.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/DictionariesCommon.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/sbin/update-dictcommon-aspell line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/update-dictcommon/aspell line 4.
dpkg: error processing package aspell-en (--remove):
  subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Removing python-software-properties (0.92.37.8) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 aspell-en
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
#
```

So, my questions are:

- How do I recover from this? Obviously, I cannot install or remove an individual package with apt until the dependencies are fixed, so I cannot handle aspell-en individually - and obviously, `install Text::Iconv` via `cpan` fails too
- Why does this install process need to locate *anything* **at all** during a  **REMOVE**? I am not installing, I am removing - I don't bloody care if components of a software are found, if I am **REMOVING** a piece of software?!

Comment: possibly related: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=161339

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall the Perl package with this module by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libtext-iconv-perl` ?

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert - tried it, cannot, because as I noted, this is a failed upgrade, so that command fails with `E: Unmet dependecies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)`, and then I run `apt -f install` as in the OP, and then this keeps running in circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's fix this problem on the low level by downloading package and install it directly:

```
apt-get download libtext-iconv-perl
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libtext-iconv-perl*.deb
```

and next resume the process with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libtext-iconv-perl
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies
```

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert - this is what I did (see my answer below), and now the `apt -f install` process continued fine ...

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to @N0rbert, this is now fixed. When I re-ran `cpan`, and then `install Text::Iconv`, I realized that a 32-bit module is being built; which failed with `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`.

Obviously, since this is a broken update, you cannot do `apt/apt-get install` nor `apt/apt-get remove` for individual packages until the dependencies for `apt` are fixed (and the fix of the dependencies for `apt` fails, as shown in OP).

The trick was to **download only** the .deb package for `libtext-iconv-perl`, and then install it via `dpkg`:

```
apt-get download libtext-iconv-perl
dpkg -i ./libtext-iconv-perl_1.7-5build2_amd64.deb
```

So, thankfully, here I got the 64-bit binaries for `libtext-iconv-perl` - and now, thankfully, `apt -f install` managed to remove `aspell-en` - and the process of fixing keeps going ...

Comment: Ok, it is great that it works :)